# What are the properties and values present in .img bootstrap's class?

Tags: html, css

I have a html file and a css (style.css) linked to it. I'm trying to link a new css (style-new.css) file to my html page. This new css file has overridden the .img class of bootstrap's and  some other properties and values are written in it.

This is effecting my html elements which have img class. I would like to override this by adding the the default properties and values of img class in my custom css (style.css).

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Switch the priority of css files. Add `style-new.css` first and `style.css` after

Comment: I'll give it a try @Morpheus

Comment: if some css files have the same selector style, style of the last linked file will affect.